# Create a Precheck job in jams powershell

Tags: powershell

I have set the jams workflow and jobs Retain Options = error.

I would like create a precheck job in jams powershell where I can cancel or block the instance of the job or workflow been started before the current workflow is finished.

So would anyone help me in creating a jams powershell inside the pscript or any other way.
I am new to this so I don't have a idea how to create it.

Comment: Welcome to SO! You should post the code your using and wanting help with as well as any pertinent details. One such detail would be, what is jams powershell?

Comment: Jams powershell is used to code in the jams scheduler for automation the jobs.

Comment: I am stuck on how to start.. I have mentioned that I just start learn about jams. So this is new to me.. and even powershell script

Comment: https://support.jamsscheduler.com/hc/en-us/articles/206191928-Getting-started-with-PowerShell

Comment: I'm always eager to learn new things as well as many others here so hopefully you follow [these guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and add a [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)